# How can I gitignore different files for different repos including pull requests?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, gitignore

```
      remote
   ______|______
  |             |
localA       localB
-file1       -file3
-file2       -file4
-file3       -file5
```

I want my remote repo to store files 1-5. I want the localA repo to only push/pull files 1-3. I want the localB repo to only push/pull files 3-5. So the goal is to have some files synched between the local repos and some files that are not, but the remote repo should store all of them. My .gitignore files work fine for committing, but then end up pulling down all the files I don't want it to. I've also tried using .git/info/exclude files but that didn't do it either. I'm in a position where I can start over from scratch if need be, but I'd prefer to configure the existing setup.

Edit for context:
This is a weird testing environment where users make changes in one area with their personal account but have to test them on a shared account in another area. I want their changes to be tracked under their individual account, not the shared account. I want the testing results tracked under the shared account, not their individual accounts.

Comment: Git does not work like that, or at least as sort-of described. Can you explain more (by editing the question) why you'd want to do that please? locala could pull/push from one branch, and localb could pull/push to a different branch - thereby potentially achieving the intended goal, for example.

Comment: Ok so let's say I have 2 branches, one for localA and one for localB. Am I able to merge both branches in the remote repo without overwriting file3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get what you want, but first you have to change what you want.

Git does not store *files;* Git stores *commits*.  A commit is like an archive of files—in fact, each commit contains a full archive of *every* file—with some extra add-on features.  The push and fetch operations (`pull` means *run `fetch` first, then run a second Git command* and it's the fetch step, not the second command, that's comparable to push here) work by transferring entire *commits*.  So, imagine each of your users is making a read-only archive of *every* file they have, and sending those every time—because that *is* what they are doing.

The name `.gitignore` (or `.git/info/exclude`, which works the same way) is quite misleading: it does not cause a file to be *ignored*.  A read-only archive is full of whatever files it contains, and none of those files can be *ignored* as they are already in the read-only archive.  When you extract that archive (with `git checkout`), you get all of its files.  Those files are now in both your working area—where you can see them and use them and even update them—and in Git's storage area, which Git calls the *staging area* or index, ready for the *next* commit (a new read-only archive).  Unless you explicitly *remove* some of these files, they will all be in the *next* commit too.

Branches, in Git, mean less than you might think as well.  Git isn't about *branches* but rather *commits*.  Branch names are simply a way to *find* some particular commit.  We need this because the actual names of individual commits are big ugly random-looking *hash IDs*, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), that no human can remember or type in correctly.  A branch name is simply the way we have the computer hold the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  The latest commit holds the hash ID of its immediately previous commit, so that from the latest commit, Git can look back one hop.  The previous commit in turn contains the hash ID of *its* previous commit, so that Git can look back one more hop, and so on.

> Ok so let's say I have 2 branches, one for localA and one for localB.

Again, branches are not for *files*.  Branches are for *finding commits*.  Each commit holds a full snapshot (archive) of *every* file—or more precisely, every file that it holds.  You can have a commit—an archive—that holds exactly one file.  But this isn't going to be very helpful, at least not with normal everyday Git tooling.  (You could write your own tooling to deal with these, but that will be a lot of work.)

> Am I able to merge both branches in the remote repo without overwriting file3?

The `git merge` operation is about *combining work*.  Consider the normal everyday merge like this:

- We take three—not two—commits, i.e., three read-only archives of every file.
- One of these three archives is the *merge base:* that commit is *shared* and hence *on both branches*.
- The remaining two commits are the most recent ones on each of the two branches.  One of these is "our" branch—the one we pick out with `git checkout` or `git switch` before we start.  The other one is "their" branch, whose name we give to the `git merge` command.
- We now have Git compare *all* the stored files in the merge base to *all* the stored files in our branch tip commit.  Whatever *changes* Git observes here—new files added, old files deleted, existing files changed—are our *changes*.
- Next, we have Git compare *all* the stored files in the merge base to *all* the stored files in *their* branch tip commit.  Whatever *changes* Git observes here are *their* changes.
- Finally, we have Git combine these two sets of changes: if we added a totally-new file, Git takes our file; if they added one, Git takes their file; if we modified `fileA`, Git keeps our change to that file; if they also modified `fileA`, Git adds that change as well.  Git then extracts all the files from the *merge base* commit and applies the *combined* changes to these files.

  If there is some problem with combining the changes, Git will stop in the middle of this process.  Note that if we changed only `fileA` and they changed only `fileB`, there will never be any problem combining these changes.  We run into combining problems when we and they touch the *same lines* in *one* file, or if we modify `fileA` and they *remove* `fileA` entirely, for instance.

  If Git is able to do all the change-combining on its own, Git applies the combined changes to the merge base—this keeps what we changed and adds what they changed—and makes a new *merge commit*, which is special in exactly one way (I'll get to this in a moment).  If not, Git stops in the middle of this process and it becomes your job—"you" being the human who ran `git merge`—to clean up the mess by providing the *correct merge result*.  Whatever you provide here, Git will *believe* it is correct, so it's best to get this right.  You then tell Git about your merge resolutions, and Git goes on to make the same merge commit it would have made if it had been able to do the combining on its own.

So, the answer to your question is a provisional "yes":

- Suppose groups X and Y start with the same commit, so that they all have the same archived files.  In this archive, there exist files named `fileA`, `fileB`, and `file3`.
- Group X creates a new branch, modifies `fileA`, and—using their branch (see below)—makes a new archive in which all files except `fileA` are the same.
- Separately (on *their* own new branch), group Y modifies `fileB` and makes a new archive in which all files except `fileB` are the same.
- You now take the main-line branch forward by picking one of their commits as the new "best combined result", then you run `git merge` on the *other* commit / branch to get the new "best combined result".  Since `file3` in all three of these archives is *the same*, there are no changes to `file3` to be made.  Git copies `file3` from the merge base archive to put in the new archive.

The reason this is a *provisional* yes is that *each group must take care to preserve, and not modify, any files that they are not supposed to change*.  If they mess with one of those files, your merge will not go so smoothly.  Note, however, that *every archive is read-only and lives forever* so it's easy to notice that—hey!—they changed files they *should not have!* and make them put those files back in a *new* archive they add on to their branch.  See example below.

#### An example

Let's start with a totally empty Git repository, one that has *no* commits and *no* branches at all:

```
mkdir repo && cd repo && git init
[Git prints messages about initializing a new repository]
```

Now you create the initial set of working-tree files: perhaps an empty `A`, an empty `B`, and your three numbered files.  You then `git add` all of them: this tells Git to copy them into Git's *index* aka *staging area*, from which Git makes the new commits.  Note that *none of these files are to be "ignored"* (again, more on this in a bit) because we want *every* file to be in *every* commit.

You now have one commit in your repository.  This one commit is the *initial commit*.  A normal new commit would link back to the previous commit, but since there is no previous commit, this one literally can't.  It has a big ugly hash ID: a unique number, one that is unique across every Git repository in the entire universe.<sup>1</sup>  Rather than guess at its number, or even abbreviate it like `a123456` or something, let's just call this commit `A`:

```
A
```

Now let's say you forgot something, or discover something that you hadn't thought of, that needs to go in `file3`.  No problem!  You adjust the copy of `file3` in your working tree—this one is an ordinary everyday file; the *archives* are in the *commits* and you don't work directly on those—and then run `git add file3`.  This `git add` copies the updated file3 into Git's staging area / index, ready to be committed.  You now run `git commit` again.

This makes a second commit—a second *full archive of every file*.  Because Git is clever, this archive literally shares storage with the first archive.  Even if `file2` is 100 megabytes large, your repository only grows a few bytes to hold the update to `file3`.  The archives are each independent of each other, yet also shared; that's the magical bit that Git achieves (it knows how to do this *because* every archive is completely read-only, and hence easily shareable).

This new commit, which we'll call `B` instead of trying to guess at its unique hash ID, points backwards to the old commit:

```
A <-B
```

The way Git knows that `B` is the *latest* commit on your main branch—which we'll call `main`; you can give it any name you like; Git still defaults to `master` although GitHub now defaults to `main`—is that the *name* `main` *points to* commit `B`, like this:

```
A <-B   <--main
```

If you now find that there is a typo in some file, you can fix this by making another new commit.  We'll call this new commit `C`.  Commit `C` will point back to existing commit `B`, and Git will store `C`'s hash ID into the branch name:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

(Note: I get deliberately lazy here and stop drawing the arrows between commits as arrows, but they're still one-way arrows.  Git works *backwards*, from most recent commit—found by using the branch name—to older commits.)

Let's say we are now ready for your testers to do their testing.  I'll continue to call them group X and group Y (to make the single letters "far away" from my single letters for commits).  We make *two new branch names* now, *both pointing to commit `C`*, so that there are *three* names for commit `C` now:

```
A--B--C   <-- main, groupX, groupY
```

---

<sup>1</sup>This uniqueness requirement is *why* the hash IDs are so big and ugly.  Technically, the ID need only be unique across every other Git repository your Git repository will ever *talk to*, but that's best ensured by making sure this ID is *totally* unique.

---

#### Testers begin testing

Your testers now use `git clone` to copy the *entire repository* full of commits.  When they do this, they get *all the commits* and *none of the branches*.  Instead, their clones have what we call *remote-tracking names*.  Let's take a look from the point of view of Group X.

```
A--B--C   <-- origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

Because they want to add *new* commits, they immediately need a branch name of their own.  If they're clever enough, they tell their Git this at `git clone` time: *please make for me the name `groupX` based on my new remote-tracking name `origin/groupX`*.  (They do this with the `-b` option to `git clone`.)  That gives them:

```
A--B--C   <-- groupX (HEAD), origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

If they're not so clever, their Git may create the wrong name for them.  Let's say they get the default `main` from GitHub:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

Note the `HEAD` added here, in parentheses: this indicates their *current branch name*.  You had one too, we just didn't bother drawing it when your only branch name was `main`.  Since `main` is the wrong name, they now need to have their Git *create* their `groupX` name, using `git checkout groupX` or `git switch groupX`.  This uses their `origin/groupX` to create their `groupX`.  Their `groupX` will point to the same commit as their `origin/groupX`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- groupX (HEAD), main, origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

Note how they now have two branch names: `main` and `groupX`.  The special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the name `groupX`.  The *remote-tracking* names all point to existing commit `C`.  The two branch names also point to existing commit `C`.  Commit `C` is thus the *newest* commit on *both* of their branches, at this point.

**All commits are read-only.**  They literally cannot change any of the existing three commits.  *All* they can do is add new commits—but that's what they should do.  They now have, in their working tree, the files extracted from the archive in commit `C`.

They can run their tests, and update `fileA` or `localA` or whatever you called this file.  This update happens in their *working tree*, which contains *all* the files extracted from commit `C`.  Then they run `git add` on their one updated file.  (They can run it on all files, with `git add -A` or `git add .`: Git will notice that the other files are unchanged and won't actually *change* anything here.)  This prepares *their* index/staging-area for making a new commit, by updating the staging copy of `fileA` or `localA` or whatever you are calling it.  (The other staging copies remain the same, even if `git add` writes to them, because they didn't *change* those files.)

They now run `git commit`.  This makes a new archive of *every file*, as a new commit, with a new unique hash ID.  Let's call it `D`, and draw it in:

```
        D   <-- groupX (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- main, origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

Note how *their* name `groupX` was updated to point to *their* new commit `D`.  Their new commit points back to existing commit `C`.

#### Meanwhile, group Y begins testing too

Group Y goes through the same series of operations, except that the *name* they'll use to keep track of *their* commit(s) is `groupY`:

```
A--B--C   <-- groupY (HEAD), origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
```

(I left out `main` this time on the assumption that they remembered the `-b` option to `git clone`.)  Eventually they end up with:

```
A--B--C   <-- origin/main, origin/groupX, origin/groupY
       \
        E   <-- groupY (HEAD)
```

#### Combining work

Note that at this point, there are *three repositories*, each of which has some *shared* commits with the same hash IDs, and each of which has some commit(s) unique to it, with unique-to-it hash IDs.  This is now time for groups X and Y to use `git push`.

There are a lot of options here but let's say that you let them do `git push` directly to some shared, writable repository.  Group X will send their new commit `D` and ask the shared writable repository to set *its* branch name `groupX` to point to commit `D`.  Group Y will do the same with their commit `E` but ask the shared writable repository to set *its* branch name `groupY`.  And, let's assume for the moment that you have direct access to this shared writable repository, so that you can now log in and look at it.  It now has this:

```
        D   <-- groupX
       /
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
       \
        E   <-- groupY
```

It's now *your* job to *combine work*.  You:

- move your `HEAD` / `main` to point to either `D` or `E` (it does not matter which one), by using `git merge`, which performs a so-called *fast forward* merge:

  ```
           D   <-- main (HEAD), groupX
          /
   A--B--C
          \
           E   <-- groupY
  ```
- run `git merge groupY` to perform the merge; and
- Git does the merge automatically because everyone did their job correctly, so that you get:

  ```
           D   <-- groupX
          / \
   A--B--C   F   <-- main (HEAD)
          \ /
           E   <-- groupY
  ```

Note how *no commit ever changes:* we add *new* commits that store the new archives.  The *branch names* move forward as we add new commits.  Git continues to work *backwards*, starting from a branch name like `groupX` and working backwards.

The one thing that is special here is that from the name `main`, we find that commit `F` is a *merge commit*, with two ways to go backwards.  These two ways lead to commits `D` and `E` respectively.  This means that if your testers need to update their files, the *next* merge you do will have a different *merge base* commit.

It's now up to your testers as to whether they (a) pick up new commit `F` and (b) update *their* branch names to incorporate commit `F`.  This isn't *necessary* as long as they do everything else right, but it will make things easier for you if they break something.

#### When things go wrong

This pattern will repeat, over and over again: someone will update *their* branch, then send *their* new commit(s) to you, and you will choose to incorporate these commits, or not.  If they break something, you can simply refuse to incorporate that commit.  For instance, suppose both groups update to `F`, then group X makes a bad commit `G`:

```
        D   G   <-- groupX
       / \ /
A--B--C   F   <-- main (HEAD), groupY
       \ /
        E
```

You can just *not take* `G`.  You can require that they make their next commit `H` with parent `F`, *abandoning* their `G`, or that they fix their `G` with a commit `H` that has a corrected archive/snapshot.  Either method suffices.  Here's what the abandoned-commit one looks like:

```
              G   [abandoned]
             /
        D   /__--H   <-- groupX
       / \ /
A--B--C   F   <-- main (HEAD), groupY
       \ /
        E
```

Since there is no *branch name* that finds commit `G` any more, it disappears from view.  Eventually, it falls out of the repository entirely (an un-find-able commit becomes eligible for "garbage collection" after some time period).

#### OK, so, what is `.gitignore` / `.git/info/exclude` for anyway?

After reading all this you should find yourself asking the above question.  The answer is that *working trees* tend to fill up with "junk" or temporary or output files that *should never be archived*.  This has two annoying side effects:

1. `git status` tells us what's in our working trees that *could* be put into the next archive, but currently isn't scheduled for that.  These are what Git calls *untracked files*.  It's annoying to have `git status` list out a thousand untracked files when they are not *supposed* to be added.
2. `git add .` or other en-masse add operations are convenient, but they'll add untracked files.

What if we could tell Git: *if this file is untracked, (1) don't complain about it, and (2) don't auto-add it with en-masse add-all-changes operations*?  That's what `.gitignore` is for: to suppress complaints and avoid automatically adding these never-to-be-archived files.

If a file is in Git's index aka staging area—which it will be if it came *out* of some archive—listing that file in a `.gitignore` or `exclude` file has no effect.  It's now *tracked*.  Only files that *aren't* in the index / staging-area, and *are* in your working tree, are *untracked*, and only these files can be "ignored" this way.  *Ignored* is the wrong term, but the right one is too long to be used as a file name.

Comment: Thanks for well thought out response. I appreciate your input!